# Como executar um construtor no Pytest?

Tags: construtor

No meu diretório de trabalho, eu tenho uma pasta que contém meu pacote e uma outra pasta com arquivos de testes. A árvore de diretórios é a seguinte:

```
Current_dir/

    MyPackage/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py

    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_package.py
```

Estou executando, no console, o comando `pytest tests`. Eu quero que seja executado primeiro o `__init__`, para que eu possa adicionar ao `sys.path` o diretório que contém a pasta do meu pacote (`"../"`). Dessa forma, eu poderia importar o meu pacote no arquivo de testes.

No entanto, o `pytest` não executa o *constructor*, gerando um `ImportError` no meu arquivo de testes. O que eu posso fazer para executar o construtor?